# how do I use <doc Table>.addTableRow()?

Tags: google-apps-script

I know that the script API for Documents is much poorer than that for Sheets but I have a few instances where I've needed to use it. In one case, I'd like to use the script to add one (or more) rows to a table but I can't get .addTableRow() to work. I get no error, but I get no added row either. Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?
Here's one example:

```
function addRows() {
  var d = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var t =  d.getBody().getTables()[0];
  var qn = d.getSelection().getRangeElements().length;
  for (var i=0;i<qn;i++) {t.appendTableRow();} //append number of rows selected--doesn't work!
}
```

although I first encountered the problem in another application where I just wanted to append a single row at the end of an otherwise successful script.

Answer (score 0):

If your familiar with how to build tables in html. Which has a table structure something like this:

```
<table>
<tr><th>First Header</th><th>Second Header</th><th>Third Header</th></tr>
<tr><td>Some Content</td><td>More Content</td><td>And End of Row</td></tr>
</table>
```

It's sort of like that. Adding the table row does nothing unless you also add the table data or content which is what comes between the td's. In the case of html you can control the style of the th's and td's because they're different tags.  In this situation you can control their styles by assigning them different styles as you build them. So here's what the code tends to look like.

```
   function addTableRow()
{
  var thStyle = {};
  thStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]=true;
  thStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE]='12';
  var tdStyle = {};
  tdStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE]='8';

  var datA = ["dog","lion","beaver","antelope"];
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bdy = doc.getBody();
  var tbl = bdy.getTables()[0];
  for(var j = 0; j < 2;j++)
  {
    var tr = tbl.appendTableRow();
    for(var i = 0 ; i < 4; i++)
    {
      var td = tr.appendTableCell(datA[i]);
      if(j==0)td.setAttributes(thStyle);
      if(j==1)td.setAttributes(tdStyle);
     }
  }
}
```

There don't seem to be very many good examples of this on the Google Site but there are some other sites that do a pretty good job of it.  I picked up most of this [here.](http://www.googleappsscript.org/home/create-table-in-google-document-using-apps-script)